# ListView: item container ignores vertical alignment

Tags: xaml, listview, winui-3, winui

I'm using a horizontal ListView from WinUI 3 to display a kind of chart with arbitrary column height:

[image]

Problem is that when there is not enough space and scroll bars appear, the layout falls apart:

[image]

This is weird, because item contaner's alignment is set to Stretch, so I expect that they should fill all vertical space provided by items panel:

```
                            <ListView.ItemsPanel>
                                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                    <VirtualizingStackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />
                                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            </ListView.ItemsPanel>
                            <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                                <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                                    <!--<Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
                                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red" />-->
                                    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                                    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Bottom" />
                                    <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="0" />
                                    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0" />
                                </Style>
                            </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
```

If I uncomment those two lines to see container borders and scroll down, I see following picture:

[image]

Any ideas about what is going wrong here? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It'd be easier to help with minimal reproducible code. Can you post code around your items?

Answer (score 0):

If you try to stretch the `ListViewItem` via their style and they don't, it could be an indicator that they are constrained by their parent (in this case the `VirtualizingStackPanel`).

You could try to change that panel for a regular `StackPanel` with `Orientation="Horizontal"` (not permanently, just to compare the behaviors) and see what happens.
It could be that some properties need to be set on `VirtualizingStackPanel` to achieve what you want.

It could also be that you fall in undefined behavior territory. When you think about it, the layout is problematic when it goes beyond the available space. The panel might not be able to stretch its items because it doesn't know what size it's going to take vertically, because that size is determined by the max height of its children, which are being layed out. We're in a layout loop and this use-case might simply not be supported.